# Repository entry within package.json

Tags: git, npm, repository, package.json

In some package.json files there is an entry called `repository` that usually has a `type` and a `url` field. One way to configure it, is like the following:

```
"repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git://github.com/isaacs/node-glob.git"
}
```

As stated on [docs.npmjs.com](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#repository) this is aimed at people who want to contribute. Hence, this sounds like an entry intended to not be read by a machine, but by a human.

I thought this entry would be quite useful if the source code behind it would be called, compiled, and integrated into the own project. Is there there possibility to do such a thing, automating download, compile, integration? Or is this entry really only an info for developers?

Comment: What do you mean by “the source code behind it”? The repository field is the location of the remote repo for the current project.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I mean exactly the source code you describe, the source repo for the current project.

Comment: Alrighty, you also refer to “own project” I’m assuming you’re referring to others who use this repo?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Not quite sure what you mean. The global thing I am trying to find out is whether there is a way to automatically do `git clone ...` and then compile + integration.

Comment: It sounds like you’re looking for a continuous integration server. Like travis-ci, circle-ci, Jenkins and the like.